# How to open a Read-only Word Document from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Every time I try to open a word document in VBA excel I get a pop up window in the background that asks me how to open it because it is tagged as read-only. I have looked at the properties of the file and it isn't read-only however it is in revision control (tortoise-SVN).

```
Sub ReadSpec()
'References
'  Microsoft Word 14.0 Object library
'
Dim Paragraphe As Object

Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("Spec.docx")
WordApp.Visible = True

WordDoc.Close
WordApp.Quit


End Sub
```

Comment: hmmm not familiar with SVN but you might try `.Open("Spec.docx",  ReadOnly=False)` or `Open("Spec.docx", ConfirmConversions=False, ReadOnly=False)`.

Comment: I'll add that as an answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

The file may be in use by another application which is why you're being told it is read-only. This isn't a problem unless you want to write to the file. If you're only trying to read from it my suggestion is to add

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

to see if it gets rid of the prompt for you. Also note that it is generally good practice to do something more along the lines of

```
Sub YourMethod
    Dim PrevDispAlerts as Boolean

    PrevDispAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'code that does something goes here

    Application.DisplayAlerts = PrevDispAlerts
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with SVN but you might try either:

```
.Open("Spec.docx", ReadOnly=False)
```

or

```
.Open("Spec.docx", ConfirmConversions=False, ReadOnly=False)
```

These suppress two common dialogs and force the default behavior. If you needed to override you would have to either make that explicit in the above code (i.e., `ReadOnly=True` to force read only) or just allow the dialog to display, using your original code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on the version of Excel. Solutions often work for one version but not another.

http://smallbusiness.chron.com/open-word-document-excel-using-vba-40430.html

I found this code worked.

```
'Open an existing Word Document from Excel
Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
'Change the directory path and file name to the location
'of the document you want to open from Excel
objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Documents\myfile.doc"
```

Answer (score -2):

hmmm not familiar with SVN but you might try

```
 .Open("Spec.docx", ReadOnly=False) or Open("Spec.docx", ConfirmConversions=False, ReadOnly=False)
```

Comment: wow this is actually an answer but you literally copied my comment on the OP verbatim -- complete with the useless "hmmm".